# Typescript Export enum based on the condition?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular based on the environment I need to export enum. I don't know wether it is correct or not?
role.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
if(environment.production) {
  export enum Role {
   User: 'user',
   Admin: 'admin'
  }
 } else {
  export enum Role {
   User: 'user',
   Admin: 'user'
  }
}
```

Based on the condidtion how to export it? Thanks

Comment: This is not the purpose of Enums. You should create a new class, or a interface, that has these properties and you assign the appropriate properties depending on the condition and you then return a instance of that class/interface. Enums are for fixed key => value pairs that should not change.

Comment: Any work around of this?

Comment: @Rijo you have two files under environments directory. One for production and one for dev. Add the production to the production file and dev to dev. I do not see any complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
export class Role {
  static User = 'user';
  static Role = (environment.production) ? 'role' : 'admin';
}
```

Comment: If you are using any generics, you'll have to use typeof everywhere after that.

Answer (score 1):

String emuns like:

```
    export enum Role {
       User = 'user',
       Admin = 'admin',
   }
```

Will be built into:

```
     "use strict";
   Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
   var Role;
   (function (Role) {
       Role["User"] = "user";
       Role["Admin"] = "admin";
   })(Role = exports.Role || (exports.Role = {}));
```

So as you can see in the end your enum would be an object. You can rewrite your code like this

```
  import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

    export const Roles = getRole();

    function getRole() {
     if (environment.production) {
       return {
         User: 'user',
         Admin: 'admin'
       };
     }

     return {
       User: 'user',
       Admin: 'user'
     };
    }
```

Comment: This is great if you don't want to rewrite all your code, it allows all the references to your enum values to stay as they were