# conditional interfaces or static class properties and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using an API provider which requires different object **property keys** to be sent based on an environment (it's a CRM using auto-generated identifiers for each custom profile fields I create).

Initially, I defined an Enum, interfaces that specified the keys, and a function to send data:

```js
export enum CustomFields {
  NAME = "2e6fbbfa-93c5-400a-ae6c-4453d3e30727",
  AGE = "c1b0de70-5c22-4aa1-9363-cd8ffee6a67d",
  ...etc,
}

export interface CreatePersonData {
   id: number;
   [CustomFields.NAME]: string;
   [CustomFields.AGE]: number;  
}

export function createPerson(data: CreatePersonData) {
  return request(url, data);
}
```

Then I found out that the auto-generated keys change in my sandbox account.

Is there a recommended way to use Enums like this which are conditional, while still being able to use them in interfaces?

I've tried the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58595552/1166285) using static class properties, but seems I can't use those as interface keys. For example:

```
export class CustomFields {
  static NAME = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' 
     ? "2e6fbbfa-93c5-400a-ae6c-4453d3e30727" 
     : "c90ce7c8-5d13-42e4-863b-8b96eb058500"
}

interface CreatePersonData {
   [CustomFields.NAME]: string; // 
}
```

This results in an error:

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1169)

Comment: assuming your using webpack, you can write the same class on two file, one for developemnt, one for prod, then swap out entire file when compiling  `new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  \.\/config\.development\.js/,
  './config.production.js'
);`https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/

Comment: @arslan2012 unfortunately Node.js (which I forgot to mention)